# MySQL how to convert one or multiple consecutive unknown characters to a single space

Tags: php, mysql, search, replace, ascii

My client has copy-pasted some text from a pdf file which was converted to MS Word document and encoded into the MySQL database. We were baffled at first because the newly encoded rows were not showing up when a string search was executed. It got weirder when even MS Excel showed no results when we did a string search.
So this made me suspect there was something in the characters that was throwing off the search so I converted a string from a profile that is showing up and the string from the one that isn't to ASCII code and here are the results:

[The two strings with their equivalent ASCII codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IXYE.png)
Where it seems like some unknown characters were placed instead of a regular whitespace.

My question is how can I convert all the `194 160` illegal characters into `32` (space) that were encoded in the database using SQL?

I would also like to address this issue in the future by automatically converting any two or more consecutive illegal characters into a single space during data entry, but how do I do a search and replace for illegal ASCII codes preferably through PHP?

Comment: `$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]/', '',$string);`

Comment: Thank you @ArtisticPhoenix for answering my second question

Comment: `any two or more consecutive illegal characters into a single space` would be `$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]{2,}/', ' ',$string);`  Not sure why you want 2 or more, but hey, what do I know.